# Ruby on Rails / SQL Server datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, date, datetime

I'm having some problem with date time. My local timezone is `UTC +0800`.

In the SQL Server, when I open up SQL Server Management Studio Express, the datetime shows as `13/8/2015 9:05:00 AM`.

With Rails on default timezone, I get the time in angular as "2015-08-13T09:05:00.000Z"

When I do `$filter('date')(date, "HH:mm Z")`, I get `17:05 +0800`

When I do `$filter('date')(date, "HH:mm Z", "+0800")`, I still get `17:05 +0800`

I tried to change rails timezone to `UTC +0800`, I get the time in angular as `2015-08-13T17:05:00.000+08:00`

When I do `$filter('date')(date, "HH:mm Z")`, I get `17:05 +0800`

When I do `$filter('date')(date, "HH:mm Z", "+0800")`, I still get `17:05 +0800`

I am confused. How can I get the $filter result to show the time `9:05`

EDIT: i watched the rails cast video and tried d.AssignedDateTime_before_type_cast and it's giving me `2015-08-13 09:05:00 UTC`. So the problem is Rails think that the datetime stored in SQL Server Database is UTC. That datetime is given to me from a Microsoft ERP system, is there any way I can make rails not think it's a UTC time? Changing the config timezone in application.rb did not work.

Comment: so it is not a angualrjs problem at all? In his case, please edit your question title and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing `config.active_record.default_timezone` in addition to `config.time_zone` in `application.rb` worked.

Answer (score -1):

Have you watched this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised)? It might help you with configuring Rails with the right timezone.

Once you have the right times coming out of the database and being rendered in your JSON response, I expect the Angular problem should be taken care of.

Comment: thanks, will take a look, so it's the times coming out of the database and rendered in my JSON response wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question, but I would start by making sure Rails is presenting the date time format you expect, before you format it with Angular's Date filter.

Comment: Somebody downvoted this (an by this also revieved a -1 for themself) In stackoverflow, you upvote answers when they are useful. If they are not useful, you just ignore them. you downvote them only when there is a serious problem with them. In this case, please give also a comment.

Comment: i watched the video and tried d.AssignedDateTime_before_type_cast and it's giving me 2015-08-13 09:05:00 UTC, is there a way to make rails not think the stored time in the database is UTC ?

Comment: Thanks @Meier. I was wondering exactly why this was down voted.

Comment: @rlarcombe i did not downvote your answer in case you're wondering if it's me

Comment: @ShinonChan - This might be helpful for you: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones